# pysvn fails to make due to -lneon not found?

Tags: centos, make, subversion, python

I am trying to install pysvn on my CentOS server and it says that -lneon is gone.
After searching their mailing lists for a bit [I found what neon means](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A--usr-bin-ld%3A-cannot-find--lcom_err-p21535583.html) but it doesn't say how can I get it?

Here's my make command output:

```
make
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u generate_svn_error_codes/create_svn_error_codes_hpp.
py /usr/local/include/subversion-1
g++ -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.
2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/pyt
hon2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -DPYC
XX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  gene
rate_svn_error_codes/generate_svn_error_codes.cpp -o generate_svn_error_codes/ge
nerate_svn_error_codes
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u create__init__.py pysvn/__init__.py.template pysvn/_
_init__.py generate_svn_error_codes/generate_svn_error_codes _pysvn_2_7.so
Info: Creating __init__.py for module _pysvn_2_7
Info: Running 'generate_svn_error_codes/generate_svn_error_codes >>pysvn/__init_
_.py'
Compile pysvn_docs.cpp
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u ../Docs/generate_cpp_docs_from_html_docs.py /usr/loc
al/include/subversion-1 ../Docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html pysvn_docs.hpp pysvn_docs.cp
p
Info: svn_include /usr/local/include/subversion-1
Info: html_doc ../Docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html
Info: cpp_header_filename pysvn_docs.hpp
Info: cpp_module_filename pysvn_docs.cpp
Info: Building against SVN 1.5.7 code 1005007
Compile pysvn_docs.hpp
touch pysvn_docs.hpp
Compile pysvn_version.hpp
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u ../Builder/brand_version.py ../Builder/version.info
pysvn_version.hpp.template
Info: Running svnversion -c ".." 2>&1
Info: revision exported
Compile pysvn.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn.o pysvn.cpp
Compile pysvn_callbacks.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_callbacks.o pysvn_callbacks.cpp
Compile pysvn_client.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client.o pysvn_client.cpp
Compile pysvn_static_strings.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_static_strings.o pysvn_static_strings.cpp
Compile pysvn_enum_string.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_enum_string.o pysvn_enum_string.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_add.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_add.o pysvn_client_cmd_add.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_changelist.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_changelist.o pysvn_client_cmd_changelist.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_checkin.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_checkin.o pysvn_client_cmd_checkin.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_copy.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_copy.o pysvn_client_cmd_copy.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_diff.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_diff.o pysvn_client_cmd_diff.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_export.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_export.o pysvn_client_cmd_export.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_info.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_info.o pysvn_client_cmd_info.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_list.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_list.o pysvn_client_cmd_list.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_lock.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_lock.o pysvn_client_cmd_lock.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_merge.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_merge.o pysvn_client_cmd_merge.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_prop.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_prop.o pysvn_client_cmd_prop.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_revprop.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_revprop.o pysvn_client_cmd_revprop.cpp
Compile pysvn_client_cmd_switch.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_client_cmd_switch.o pysvn_client_cmd_switch.cpp
Compile pysvn_transaction.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_transaction.o pysvn_transaction.cpp
Compile pysvn_revision.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_revision.o pysvn_revision.cpp
Compile pysvn_docs.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_docs.o pysvn_docs.cpp
Compile pysvn_path.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_path.o pysvn_path.cpp
Compile pysvn_arg_processing.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_arg_processing.o pysvn_arg_processing.cpp
Compile pysvn_converters.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_converters.o pysvn_converters.cpp
Compile pysvn_svnenv.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_svnenv.o pysvn_svnenv.cpp
Compile pysvn_profile.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o pysvn_profile.o pysvn_profile.cpp
Compile cxxsupport.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o cxxsupport.o /home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src/cxxsupport.cxx
Compile cxx_extensions.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o cxx_extensions.o /home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src/cxx_extensi
ons.cxx
Compile cxxextensions.o
gcc -c -Wall -fPIC -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1 -I/home/omerk
atz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -I/usr/loc
al/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I.  -o cxxextensions.o /home/omerk
atz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src/cxxextensions.c
Compile IndirectPythonInterface.o
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -frtti -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx
-6.2.1 -I/home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src -I/usr/local/include/
python2.7 -I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/include/httpd -I. -DNDEBUG -D
PYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3 -Dinit_pysvn=init_pysvn_2_7 -Dinit_pysvn_d=init_pysvn_2_7_d  -
o IndirectPythonInterface.o /home/omerkatz/pysvn-1.7.4/Import/pycxx-6.2.1/Src/In
directPythonInterface.cxx
Compile pysvn/_pysvn_2_7.so
g++ -shared  -o pysvn/_pysvn_2_7.so pysvn.o pysvn_callbacks.o pysvn_client.o pys
vn_static_strings.o pysvn_enum_string.o pysvn_client_cmd_add.o pysvn_client_cmd_
changelist.o pysvn_client_cmd_checkin.o pysvn_client_cmd_copy.o pysvn_client_cmd
_diff.o pysvn_client_cmd_export.o pysvn_client_cmd_info.o pysvn_client_cmd_list.
o pysvn_client_cmd_lock.o pysvn_client_cmd_merge.o pysvn_client_cmd_prop.o pysvn
_client_cmd_revprop.o pysvn_client_cmd_switch.o pysvn_transaction.o pysvn_revisi
on.o pysvn_docs.o pysvn_path.o pysvn_arg_processing.o pysvn_converters.o pysvn_s
vnenv.o pysvn_profile.o cxxsupport.o cxx_extensions.o cxxextensions.o IndirectPy
thonInterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -lsvn_client-1 -
lsvn_diff-1 -lsvn_repos-1 -lcom_err -lresolv -lexpat -lneon -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lneon
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pysvn/_pysvn_2_7.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Why not install the distro-packaged software, `yum install neon-devel` (not sure of the name)? Also, why not install the distro-packaged pysvn?

Comment: Because at the time of posting I didn't know what yum does, also it does not work. Config Error: Error accessing file for config file://///etc/yum.repos.d/WebFacti
on.repo

Comment: Can you please ask here (new Question) for help with troubleshooting that yum error you are getting. You really got to use distro-supplied tools, unless you have a very good reason not to (EG, you want bleeding-edge software not yet packaged by the distro).

Comment: It's simple, I don't have root access and yum is not allowed without root access.

Comment: Can you use @username next time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019.

Comment: How are you able to install pysvn without root access?

Comment: @Tshepang: Downloaded it, used make and that's it.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you are running it from the build directory.

Comment: @Tshepang yes, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `-lneon` solves this for me.

Comment: How did you remove `-lneon`?

Comment: @Tshepang He probably meant removing it from the makefile. It's rather odd that it would be included if the project didn't actually depend on it though

Comment: I removed it from the makefile. Turns out you only need it to connect through http and my script runs locally.